# How can I add a comment when I decline an invite in iCal or Apple Mail?

Tags: macos, mac, apple-mail, calendar.app

I'm using iCal to manage my calendar on an Exchange server. In outlook, when I accepted or declined a meeting, I was able to add a comment telling the sender why I couldn't make the meeting. With iCal, it just rudely declines the meeting with no ability to add a comment.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

In iCal, you can. Just double-click the invitation in your inbox, and the event inspector will pop up:

[image]

Comment: How do you get the comment field to show up?

Comment: When you’ve been invited to an event, the comment field should be there, right above the “Maybe”, “Decline”, and “Accept” buttons. What do you see?

Comment: I was paraphrasing the deleted message of a user who asked this – maybe it's clearer now. I personally can't say what their problems were. Thanks though :)

Comment: Anyone knows if that is possible from Mail as well? Declining and add comment?